# What does Ramban refer to with the term "hidden miracles"?

Tags: reward-punishment, miracle, ramban, hashgacha, nature

Ramban posits (many times, see links below) that there are open miracles that don't conform with the laws of nature which are used to establish eternal truths vs hidden miracles which do work within nature which God employs for reward/punishment.

Ramban holds that God responds to peoples actions via nature despite it not being natural for nature to respond to moral/immoral actions and notwithstanding peoples inability to detect God's hand in it (with regard to individual recompense, when it comes to national reward/punishment it is indeed discernable).

My understanding of Rambans position is that by and large (when it doesn't affect recompense for human deeds) nature continues to operate per it's own laws and without God's constant input.

In my thinking if God directly controls everything it would no longer be termed a miracle which necessarily denotes a divine intervention but rather one long continuous miracle (which we would call nature).

A fellow in my shul disagrees and thinks it means that God micromanages everything.

What do folks think?

See eg
https://mg.alhatorah.org/SP/Ramban/Bereshit/17.1 https://mg.alhatorah.org/SP/Ramban/Shemot/6.2
https://mg.alhatorah.org/Parshan/Ramban/Shemot/13.16#m4e3n0
https://mg.alhatorah.org/SP/Ramban/Vayikra/26.11

Answer (score 0):

This is a good explanation of what you’re asking about by Orthodox Rabbi Ariel Bar Tzadok.

If nature responds to us it’s still nature and natural..by that it means God may use say an earth quake to punish or good harvest to bless.

Does nature really respond to us? I’m not sure, I don’t think we can just act good and suddenly expect a good harvest or have protection from say a plague but.

But my understanding is that God indeed does control everything but through a natural way……and at times super natural way as He did as in Egypt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B41FfZxG0uY